# SFML game not compiling on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++, sfml

I've been working on a game using SFML for a while now and it's been going great working on it on my Linux and Mac machines. Recently, I tried compiling the game on Windows and ran into many issues.

I'm using g++ and a makefile.

`g++ -std=c++17 -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-reorder -LSFML-2.5.1/lib -ISFML-2.5.1/include -o dungy Animation.o Camera.o Dust.o DustParticle.o Entity.o Game.o main.o Player.o PlayerTrail.o Room.o Textures.o Tile.o -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

I get tons of undefined references like this when I run make (link to full ouput below):

```
Animation.o: In function `Animation::Animation(sf::Sprite*, int, bool)':
C:\Users\foxhu\Documents\Programming\C++\dungy/Animation.cpp:9: undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Sprite15getGlobalBoundsEv'

C:\Users\foxhu\Documents\Programming\C++\dungy/SFML-2.5.1/include/SFML/Graphics/RectangleShape.hpp:41: undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'
```

A similar error is outputted when using Visual Studio [following the SFML website's tutorial exactly] but it's mostly made up of random characters.

[Here's a link to the full output including the g++ command](https://pastebin.com/By8NPPJx)

I'm using the newest SFML version and have used g++ in the past to compile a game using almost the exact same makefile, so I'm dumbfounded as to why this isn't working and can find nothing online to help me after hours of looking and trying to solve this issue. The game works perfectly on both Mac and Linux using g++ and the same makefile

One final thing is that the website for SFML says to *make sure* compiler versions 100% match, I downloaded the one they provided for MinGW 7.3.0 (32-bit) and downloaded the proper SFML version to match that.

Edit:

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/Ff2jNime) the full makefile if for some reason it's needed

Comment: Well it's clear from the error message that the undefined reference is to a function called getGlobalBounds of a class called Sprite. This is an SFML function, so you are not linking the SFML libraries correctly. This is not a compilation issue, it's a linker issue.

Comment: A piece of advice to avoid surprises like this at a late stage of development: always set up  continuous integration (CI) system that automatically builds every commit you make on all relevant platforms, right from the start.

Comment: @john That's why I'm confused because it's exactly how it "should be" (as far as I know, no one has said any different) and I even have the exact g++ version that's required as well as I am linking exactly how I have done in the past and how people do it on the SFML forums.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'll have to try that in the future

Comment: @HKVariant 32-bit vs 64-bit conflict is always a possibility

Comment: @john I've tried both versions of SFML [32 and 64 for MinGW] a couple hours ago, should have updated my post my bad, so sadly no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to use the debug libraries, which I don't have to use on *any* other platform.

The makefile I now use has the following flags:

`LDFLAGS = -lsfml-graphics-d -lsfml-audio-d -lsfml-window-d -lsfml-system-d`

Before, I had these `LDFLAGS` without the `-d` on the end.

Not sure why this is different on Windows than Mac or Linux, but it continues my disdain for using Windows when programming.